# Persist sensitive data in browser? Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, security, cryptography, persistence

I was wondering if these is some kind of technique so persist sensitive data out of a web app. I know that you should **never** store sensitive data in the local storage or cookies.

When logging in a website a browser usually asks if it should persist you username and password. Where is it stored? How secure is it? And the most important question, can you access it using javascript / browser built-in functions?

My Scenario: I generate an rsa key pair once (I know random of javascript isn't that good) and need to persist my private key in a secure place in the browser, so in the next session I can access it and decrypt some data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is service oriented you want to use `OAuth` if this is just for login you would want to use `OpenId Provider`.  Let me know if you want to know more, but from a security standpoint the user has to authenticate everytime.  Otherwise, a "hacker" could take the stored item and pretend to be the user known as hijacking session.  The browser memorizing the username and password can only be accessed using the browser not JavaScript, it is stored in a "encrypted" file...

Comment: I use MVC 3 for all server side logic. And the login and session stuff is the standard MVC authentication process using the membership provider. I "just" need a way to store my private key on the client in a secure way, if possible at all.

Comment: it isn't secure to store on the users side, on authentication just re-send the private key.  Otherwise, someone can access this stored item and hijack it.

Comment: It's not the problem of authentication. I only need to generate my key pair once per browser. Private key's are never sent anywhere.

Comment: But they could easily be generated and then stored for each user.  If i'm still lost then I don't understand your Goal which would make me be able to give you some code or an example.

Comment: Yes we store our generated public key on the server. But we need to keep out private key on the client. It should never leave the client machine. Our problem is to persist our private key on the local machine in a secure place.

Comment: You would need to ask them to download it and install it into their certificate store.  Other than that...I don't know what i'd do.  Also depending on your use case there might be a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to do basic threat analysis. It helps to recognise what attack vector take into account and then you can choose the right method of protecting the key. There are several possibilities of key protection. See following examples:

- you can rely on browser origin policy and assume your JS code as trusted and store the key in localstore - key is not protected from an adversary having access to the user profile
- you can let the user enter reasonably strong password each time then private need to be accessed and store the key using password based encryption and then the encrypted private key can be stored anywhere (localstore, cookie) - an adversary capable of accessing user password is able to get the key
- you can create private key encryption key by combining user password and some secret sent by server after successful authentication of the user -