# Store sensitive data in browser, so it's inaccessible to other websites

Tags: javascript, cookies, encryption, browser, local-storage

How do I put sensitive credentials in the browser so they can be accessed by the javascript on the webpage, but not by the server or other websites?

I'm building a website that displays AES encrypted messages to users. A message is retrieved through an API and stored on my server. A user can log in and enter his key to decrypt in the browser, like this:

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#decryption_form", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var key       = $("#key").val();                                  // The key is retrieved through a form input div
  var iv        = key.substring(32);                                // The initialization vector is a part of the key submitted by the user
  var encrypted = $("#message").attr("encrypted");                  // The encrypted message that was fetched from the server was added as an attribute to a div
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv }); // The message is decrypted
  $("#message").html(decrypted);                                    // The decrypted message is displayed to the user
});
```

I've noticed that [ProtonMail](https://protonmail.com/faq) - a zero knowledge email provider who put your PGP keypair in the browser to be decrypted with your credentials - can persist the sensitive credentials even when you refresh the webpage or copy/paste the URL into the same browser tab (but not if you paste the URL into a new tab). Their source code is [open source](https://github.com/ProtonMail/WebClient), but too complicated for me to understand.

This makes me think I must somehow be able to safeguard sensitive credentials, and even persist the data for users who navigate between my webpages in the same browser tab (without the need to send it through my server).

[This post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35530/where-and-how-to-store-private-keys-in-web-applications-for-private-messaging-wi) discusses the topic, but without canonical/concrete answers. There is also [this 3 year old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030684/persist-sensitive-data-in-browser-possible) but comments are mostly about why OP needs to store sentive data in the browser at all.

Comment: Your main options are [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and cookies. Note that the user of the browser can access the keys, but that's probably OK in your case.

Comment: Maybe with a token inside a cookie?

Comment: You should store sensitive information in encrypted format itself and until you shared your private key nobody will able to decrypt that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web storage ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)) is origin-specific. If my origin stores data there, yours cannot read it from there (modulo browser bugs).

Cookies are also site-specific (and can be path-specific), but cookies get transmitted on the wire, and with web storage being extremely well-supported now (and with a much, much better API), there's no real reason to use cookies for something like this and at least a couple of really good reasons not to.

Note that nothing prevents the end user from viewing things in web storage or cookies through the browser's built-in Dev Tools. But as you've said the keys in question are the user's own, presumably that's only a problem if someone gains access to their machine...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You refer to web storage, but as I read it there are different kinds of web storage. Your MDN link is specifically for LocalStorage, so is that it? And if yes, could you maybe submit a few lines of code for reference? As I read it this could be done with `localStorage.setItem("key", "123");` and `localStorage.getItem("key");`, but I need to be sure that it's the correct approach.

Comment: @ChristofferJoergensen: Web storage consists of `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. The only difference between them is expiration: `sessionStorage` expires at the end of a session (see the spec for what a session is), `localStorage` doesn't. For what you're talking about, I suspect you want `localStorage`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you for the great anwser! One quick question though. What about browser extensions? They can access web storage of any page. So, if a user installs a malicious extension their data saved in web storage can be accessed by the extension. Am I right? Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov: Right, extensions that can run code in the context of the page can indeed tap into the page's web storage. A question asking what, if anything, can be done about that (if it hasn't already been asked) could be a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in cookies, session, local storage is accessible to users by debugging tools or other way.

You have option of strong encryption only which is hard to decrypt(but possible in some cases) :-)

Comment: Please explain: "hard to decrypt(but possible in some cases)".